# FilePointer refuses to open

Tags: php, file-io

I'm trying to make a dropdown list using a text file with separate countries listed line by line.

The issue is that, for whatever reason, my file refuses to open.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once('upload.controller.php');
$filePath = $path.'/../includes/_notes/countries.txt';
$handle = fopen($filePath, "r");


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/css/adsmanager.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/.."></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--<form method="post" action="upload.controller.php">-->
            <!--<select>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/countries.js" /></script> -->
                <?php
                    
                    if ($handle) {
                            
                        while(($buffer = fgets($file)) != false) {
                            var_dump($buffer);
                        }
                        
                        if (!feof($handle)) {
                            die("failed to open file"); 
                        }
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                ?>
            <!--</select>
        </form>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

along with my output:

```
string(66) "/var/www/patention/modules/upload/../includes/_notes/countries.txt" failed to open file
```

Am I doing something wrong? I took from the example listed straight on the
[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). Along with [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your file seems wrong to me:

```
"/var/www/patention/modules/upload/../includes/_notes/countries.txt"
```

`..` is used for relative directories.

If `countries.txt` is located within `includes/_notes/` and `includes` is in the parent directory of where your .php script is, change the path to just

```
../includes/_notes/countries.txt
```

In short, don't append `$path` to `$filePath`

**EDIT:**

In this line:

```
while(($buffer = fgets($file)) != false)
```

change to

```
while(($buffer = fgets($handle)) != false)
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before and unfortunately it didn't work. That's why I tried the realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) path, and appended it to the filepath. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, which is the weird thing. I just have a die statement which goes if feof($handle) returns false.

Comment: see edits to my answer. `$file` is undefined in your code. It should be `$handle`